# Approximating $\mathbb{P}(X_t \geq c)$ with the process' limit

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, approximation, large-deviation-theory

I stumbled over the following problem while trying to prove LDP's for branching processes. However, I state the problem more generally:

assume $(X_t)_t$ be a stochastic process, with $X_t\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ a.s., further we know that 
$$
e^{at}X_t\rightarrow W>0
$$
almost surely, as $t$ goes to infinity. Now I am interested in the probabilities 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t \geq c).
$$
The problem that concerns me is that I'd like to write 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t \geq c) \approx \mathbb{P}(e^{-at} W \geq c)
$$
for $t$ sufficiently large.

I am pretty sure it is not that simple, since somehow I'd need more precise estimates on the convergence speed of $e^{at}X_t$.
When trying to prove it, I used the following inequality for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t \geq c)
\leq 
\mathbb{P}(X_t \geq c, |X_t- e^{-at}W|< \varepsilon) + \mathbb{P}(|X_t- e^{-at}W|\geq \varepsilon)
$$
which yields 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t \geq c)
\leq
\mathbb{P}(W +\varepsilon\geq ce^{at}) + \mathbb{P}(|e^{at}X_t- W|\geq \varepsilon e^{at}).
$$
But this means that I need to know that the second term is sufficiently small and vanishes when plugging the probabilities into $\frac{1}{e^{at}}\log (\cdot)$, this is where the large deviation goal comes into play again.

I feel like having the wrong ansatz here or just thinking too complicated. I am happy about any kind of advice or reference to literature. Thanks a lot.